# CORS error when trying to post image with js and Imgur API

Tags: javascript, axios, imgur

I'm trying to upload an image with the [API of imgur](https://apidocs.imgur.com/?version=latest#intro) but I'm getting those errors (cors) : [image]

Here is my code (I'm using axios and I'm on localhost)

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/axios/dist/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
  // Uploading image to imgur
  var formData = new FormData()
  formData.append("image", "https://2img.net/u/3011/13/03/74/avatars/9905-61.png") // Don't worry about that
  formData.append("type", "URL")
  axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: 'https://api.imgur.com/3/image',
      withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + this.clientId
      }, // clientId
      data: formData
    })
    .then(function(response) {
      console.log(response);
      self.preview[key].isUploading = false // Showing the success
      self.preview[key].link = response.data.link
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
      self.preview[key].isUploading = false // Showing the error
      self.preview[key].error = true
      console.log(error);
    })
</script>
```

Can you help me ? Thanks anyway

Comment: Please try the rest call without giving 

withCredentials: true,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': 'Client-ID ' + this.clientId
      },

if you see in the error message , there is no authentication required to hit this API. So remove the headers part and check . It should work fine for you .

Comment: any luck on this ? Did you error resolve?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. The API needs auth and I tried without but that's obviously not working